# Clean a nested list

Tags: r

I have a list of dates

```
d = list(list(structure(c(18292, 18321, 18352, 18382, 18413, 18443, 
18474, 18505, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18627), class = "Date")), 
    list(structure(c(18658, 18686, 18717, 18747, 18778, 18808, 
    18839, 18870, 18900, 18931, 18961, 18992), class = "Date")
```

The way to access the list inside the list is to do

```
d[[1]][[1]]
```

I wanted to manipulate the list such that I only need to do d[[1]] to access the first element. However, when I try to unlist it turns it turns into

```
> unlist(d)
 [1] 18292 18321 18352 18382 18413 18443 18474 18505 18535 18566 18596 18627 18658 18686 18717 18747 18778 18808 18839 18870 18900
[22] 18931 18961 18992
```

Why do the dates turn into numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `recursive = FALSE`

```
> unlist(d, recursive = FALSE)[[1]]
 [1] "2020-01-31" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-31" "2020-04-30" "2020-05-31"
 [6] "2020-06-30" "2020-07-31" "2020-08-31" "2020-09-30" "2020-10-31"
[11] "2020-11-30" "2020-12-31"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purrr::flatten` -

```
l <- purrr::flatten(d)
l

#[[1]]
# [1] "2020-01-31" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-31" "2020-04-30" "2020-05-31" "2020-06-30"
# [7] "2020-07-31" "2020-08-31" "2020-09-30" "2020-10-31" "2020-11-30" "2020-12-31"

#[[2]]
# [1] "2021-01-31" "2021-02-28" "2021-03-31" "2021-04-30" "2021-05-31" "2021-06-30"
# [7] "2021-07-31" "2021-08-31" "2021-09-30" "2021-10-31" "2021-11-30" "2021-12-31"

l[[1]]

# [1] "2020-01-31" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-31" "2020-04-30" "2020-05-31" "2020-06-30"
# [7] "2020-07-31" "2020-08-31" "2020-09-30" "2020-10-31" "2020-11-30" "2020-12-31"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `do.call` in `base R`

```
do.call(c, lapply(d, `[[`, 1))`
```